# Connection Refused error on Postgres database creation using Npgsql Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am trying to create and use a PostgreSQL database with my .NET Core application. I'm using Entity Framework Core provided by Npgsql, and I'm going for the 'code-first' approach. However, when I try to generate the database (using either migrations or the "Database.EnsureCreated()" method) I always get the same error:

**Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): Connection refused.**

I have tried both on Windows and Linux, and I've gotten the same result.

The packages I've added for my project are:

- *Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL* version 3.1.3
- *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design* version 3.1.3

My project uses .NET Core 3.1

Here's my code:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;

namespace PostgresTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    public class PeopleContext : DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=12345678");
    }
    public class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: To be clear, when I use migrations, creating the migration itself succeeds, but I will still get the error mentioned above when I use the 'database update' command afterwards.

Comment: you might be using wrong connection string. found this https://medium.com/faun/asp-net-core-entity-framework-core-with-postgresql-code-first-d99b909796d7

Comment: @ManishTiwari I tried changing the connection string to what the article you linked to showed, but no luck. I still get the same error message

Comment: migration is working because it will check the old snapshot and create new migration (not using DB), but when you run update DB command it will try to connect to DB, so I think your connection string might be wrong. can you check the port, user name and password? or try to connect directly using some tool (like SSMS for SQL server)

Comment: is there any inner exception available?

Comment: yup code first means it will create the DB but it will run the SQL queries when you run Update database command. can you try to use this (https://www.pgadmin.org/) tool and use credentials you are using? (this is only to check whether you are using correct credentials or not )

Comment: Okay, there is definitely something I'm not grasping here... Keep in mind that I am completely new to PostgreSQL. You are telling me to check if the credentials are correct, but I just pulled a meaningless username and password out of thin air here... The credentials I'm using doesn't relate to anything yet. I thought that if I create a db 'code-first' then I would choose a username and password in the code, and then a db with those credentials would be generated, so that the credentials for the db would fit my code. Is that correct or not?

Comment: @Manish Okay, there is definitely something I'm not grasping here... Keep in mind that I am completely new to PostgreSQL. You are telling me to check if the credentials are correct, but I just pulled a meaningless username and password out of thin air here... The credentials I'm using doesn't relate to anything yet. I thought that if I create a db 'code-first' then I would choose a username and password in the code, and then a db with those credentials would be generated, so that the credentials for the db would fit my code. Is that correct or not?

Comment: ohh,  for using any database first you need a database server.  can you follow this https://code-maze.com/configure-postgresql-ef-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download PostgreSQL server from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads and update your connection string as per your configuration. 

for more https://code-maze.com/configure-postgresql-ef-core/

Comment: Thank you. None of the articles and guides I read mentioned that I had to install the server. I'll try it later tonight and see if I get it to work :)

Comment: I will as soon as I get to test out your solution :)
I haven't had the time to do so yet, but it look's like I'll have time tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection is bad. try to change `HOST` by `SERVER`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)=>
                 //options.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=postgres;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=12345678"); 
    options.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Database=postgres;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=12345678");
```